# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- I am trying to download the file from the grid.

  - when I click open first window link a popup opens.
  - in that popup you will see a grid.
  - but right now you will see the grid but an error is happening at the below line.
  - I am trying to download the file like this functionality
    https://jsfiddle.net/335t5aow/

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null

```or-tag-here
template: "<a class=\"sportsDataPlayer\" onclick=\"window.open('#= FileName#', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\">#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"
```

- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing code below

http://jsfiddle.net/savyjgg2/2/

```or-tag-here
template: "<a class=\"sportsDataPlayer\" onclick=\"window.open('#= FileName#', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\">#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"    
var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
var data = new Blob([csv]);
var a2 = document.getElementById(".sportsDataPlayer");
alert("I am here");
a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

Comment: `.sportsDataPlayer` is not an ID. It is a class selector. You mean `document.querySelector(".sportsDataPlayer")` - or since you use jQuery, `$(".sportsDataPlayer").attr("href",URL.createObjectURL(data))`

Comment: Am not seeing any error

Comment: @RameshRajendran `document.getElementById(".sportsDataPlayer");` does not work. `".sportsDataPlayer"` is not an ID and cannot be used in any document.getXXX

Comment: Hey can you update in the fiddle...it's confusing

Comment: Just change `var a2 = document.getElementById(".sportsDataPlayer"); a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);` to `$(".sportsDataPlayer").attr("href",URL.createObjectURL(data)‌​)` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j0bf1w8q/

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

[Ja Ja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8570821/ja-ja) I have updated the fiddle, but it is only a partial workout (only first file will be downloaded). To render the file as downloadable you'll have to use [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute in `<a>` tag.

And in your JS code, you'll have to make changes in logic accordingly so that [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute will be applied to each file name separately.

Try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/savyjgg2/39/)**, there was just a small correction

Changes were,

1. `var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");`
2. Changed from `class=\"sportsDataPlayer\"` to `id=\"sportsDataPlayer\"`

Comment: Exactly I trying to post this answer. But the problem is fiddle(yours also) only works first time :( ...

Comment: @RameshRajendran sorry I didn't get what you're trying to say

Comment: thanks for your reply...but still if I click download csv its not downloading....can you tell how to fix it :(

Answer (score -1):

**Bug here:** `var a2 = document.getElementById(".sportsDataPlayer");`

**Fix:** `var a2 = document.getElementsByClassName("sportsDataPlayer");`

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection